# Normal Numbers in different bases

Tags: number-theory

If a number is [normal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalNumber.html) in a base $b$, it is [absolutely normal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsolutelyNormal.html). 
Is this an open question or is there a counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ and $s$ are multiplicatively independent integers, then it is known that there are (lots of) numbers that are normal to base $r$ but not to base $s$. I think Wolfgang Schmidt may have proved this, and there is also work by Andy Pollington.

EDIT: a reference is Wolfgang M. Schmidt, Über die Normalität von Zahlen zu verschiedenen Basen, Acta Arith. 7 1961/1962 299–309, MR0140482 (25 #3902). This builds on earlier work of Cassels.

Comment: Here's a link to a freely accessible copy: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa7/aa7311.pdf